# Disabling User Swipes only in certain direction on UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I’m having trouble with a UITableviewController embedded in a UIPageViewController…the system can’t distinguish between a swipe left to change pages and a swipe to delete an item in the UITableView.  This particular UITableViewController happens to be on the last page of the PageViewController, so since swiping left doesn’t really do anything (nothing to the right) can I disable PageViewController from detecting swipes when current page == 3.  The tricky part is I only want to ignore swipes to the left (so that the tableView reads the left swipe as a swipe to delete), whereas I want to still detect a swipe right so that the user can navigate back to page 2.

UIPageViewController code:

```
class WorkoutPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {


    //var pageControl = UIPageControl()
    var referenceToNewWorkoutKingVC: NewWorkoutKingViewController?


    // MARK: UIPageViewControllerDataSource

    lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {

        var viewControllers = [UIViewController]()

        if referenceToNewWorkoutKingVC?.sessionType == goalieSessionString || referenceToNewWorkoutKingVC?.sessionType == refSessionString || referenceToNewWorkoutKingVC?.sessionType == coachSessionString || referenceToNewWorkoutKingVC?.sessionType == openSkateSessionString {

            viewControllers = [self.newVc(viewController: "NewIceDataTableViewController"),
                               self.newVc(viewController: "NewHealthDataTableViewController")]

        } else {
            viewControllers = [self.newVc(viewController: "NewIceDataTableViewController"),
                               self.newVc(viewController: "NewHealthDataTableViewController"),
                               self.newVc(viewController: "NewShiftTableViewController")]

        }


       return viewControllers
    }()

     let impact = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.FeedbackStyle.medium)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self


        // This sets up the first view that will show up on our page control
        if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
            setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                               direction: .forward,
                               animated: true,
                               completion: nil)
        }

    }



    func newVc(viewController: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewController)
    }




    // MARK: Delegate methods
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]
        referenceToNewWorkoutKingVC?.pageControl.numberOfPages = orderedViewControllers.count
        referenceToNewWorkoutKingVC?.pageControl.currentPage = orderedViewControllers.index(of: pageContentViewController)!


    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        //Haptic when pages switch, code from: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-generate-haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator
        impact.prepare()
        impact.impactOccurred()
    }

    // MARK: Data source functions.
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        // User is on the first view controller and swiped left to loop to
        // the last view controller.
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            //return orderedViewControllers.last
            // Uncommment the line below, remove the line above if you don't want the page control to loop.
            return nil
        }

        guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

        // User is on the last view controller and swiped right to loop to
        // the first view controller.
        guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
            //return orderedViewControllers.first
            // Uncomment the line below, remove the line above if you don't want the page control to loop.
            return nil
        }

        guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to disable the `bounces` property to `false` of `UIPageViewController` subviews `UIScrollView`

Comment: It should work fine if your list is at last page, Just check/validate swipe to delete code is in place and works

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
func managePageControllerBounces(isEnable : Bool) {

    for view in pageViewController.view.subviews {
    
        if view is UIScrollView {
            let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView
            scrollView?.bounces = isEnable
        }
    }
}
```

> Toggle bounces as per requirement

self.manegePageControllerBounces(isEnable: false)

Hope it's help to you....

Comment: Thanks!  This does help a little, the reduction of the bouncing makes it a little easier to swipe to delete, but its still kind of difficult and takes multiple tries.  Is there anything else I can do to make it easier to swipe to delete?  It almost feels as if the gesture recognizer inside the tableView's cell is too small

Comment: Yes I added so you can see when the delete action has been triggered.